# How do I write inter-related methods/closures the "Groovy" way?

Tags: groovy, closures

I need to convert a Map of config values to a string like this:

{"key" => "value", "key2" => "value2", ...}

Occasionally a value might be another map of config values, so for that value, I need something like a recursive call back into the same conversion process, producing:

{... "key3" => {"subkey" => "subvalue", ...}, ...}

I come from a Java background and am struggling to find the right Groovy/closure-based way to do this.  Here's what I have so far:

```
static String toConfigString(Map config) {
    return "{${config.collect {toConfigEntryString(it)}.join(', ')}}"
}

static String toConfigEntryString(entry) {
    return "\"$entry.key\" => ${entry.value instanceof Map ? toConfigString(entry.value) : "\"$entry.value\""}"
}
```

Since the first method calls the second method, and the second method turns around and calls back into the first method, I'm not sure how to write this as, say, one decent closure that I could just pass to the initial collect invocation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Recursion:

```
def map = [
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: [
        d: 4, 
        e: [ f: 5, g: 7 ]
    ]
]

def convertToString(Map item) {
    item.collect { k, v ->
        v instanceof Map ? "{'$k' => ${convertToString(v).join(/, /)} }" : "{'$k' => '$v'}"
    } 
}

assert convertToString( map ).join(/, /) == 
 /{'a' => '1'}, {'b' => '2'}, {'c' => {'d' => '4'}, {'e' => {'f' => '5'}, {'g' => '7'} } }/
```

Comment: I had to tweak your example slightly to get the braces and commas in the right place, but it's just what I needed.  Thanks!
```def toLoginModuleString(Map config) {
        '{' + config.collect { k, v ->
            "\"$k\" => " + (v instanceof Map ? toLoginModuleString(v) : "\"$v\"")
        }.join(', ') + '}'
    }```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy can choose which method call based on the type at runtime. You can just define two functions : one for a Map, one for all other case, and just call your function recursively

```
def dump(object) {
  "'${object}'"
}
def dump(Map config) {
​​​​​​​​​​​​  '{' + ​config.collect { key, value -> "'${key}' => ${dump(value)}" }.join(", ")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ + '}'
}

def s = [a:"prop", b:[key:"value"]]
assert dump(s) == "{'a' => 'prop', 'b' => {'key' => 'value'}}"
```